# Trouble with JSON Simple library in java

Tags: java, json

Okay, so lets say that the following is my JSON file. I can get the ID and name from the file just fine, but with the listings, it appears that it is only reading the finally listings into each person. So John and Dave both have the listings that Steve has. Do you know where I'm going wrong with this?

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"John",
        "listings":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "other_id":34,
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "other_id":16,
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "other_id":39,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Dave",
        "listings":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "other_id":156,
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "other_id":189,
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "other_id":312,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Steve",
        "listings":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "other_id":876,
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "other_id":534,
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "other_id":456,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And my java code

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(reader);

for (Object object : array){
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
    int id = (int) jsonObject.get("id");
    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");

    ArrayList<Listing> listing = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray listings = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("listings");

    for(Object item : listings){
        JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) item;
        int itemID = (int) jsonItem.get("id");
        int otherID = (int) jsonItem.get("other_id");

        Listing temp = new Listing(itemID, otherID);

        listing.add(temp);

    }

    people.add(new Person(id, name, listing));

}

for (Person person : people) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + person.getId() + ", " + " Name: " + person.getName());
    for (Listing list : person.getListing()) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + list.getID() + ", " + " OtherID: " + list.getOtherID());
    }
}
```

Comment: "other_id"876 - you miss colon

Comment: You haven't shown what you're *doing* with the results. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: When you say John and Dave has the same `listings` as Steve, I can't help but think you are overwriting your `listings` somewhere. Just speculation though -- you need to post what you did as @JonSkeet said.

Comment: listing.add(id, otherID) is an ArrayList.add(int index,E element), happily you indexes are  1,2,3. So otherID getting replaced.

Comment: @aug Yeah, had one too many copy&paste and was overwriting. You have no idea how long i've been looking at this, how dumb I feel right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more easy to use jackson parser.

```
ObjectMapper mapper;
mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<Person>>(){});
```

It will do all the work for you (populate the Person object)

Answer (score 0):

The `listing.add(id, otherID)` you are using is an `ArrayList.add(int index,E element)` So I have changed a little bit check this working.

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.length(); index++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(index);
        int id = (int) jsonObject.get("id");
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        List<Listing> listing = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray listings = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("listings");
        for (int index1 = 0; index1 < listings.length(); index1++) {
            JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) listings.get(index1);
            int itemID = (int) jsonItem.get("id");
            int otherID = (int) jsonItem.get("other_id");
            Listing listing2 = new Listing(itemID, otherID);
            listing.add(listing2);
            System.out.println(name + " " + itemID + " " + otherID);
        }
        people.add(new Person(id, name, listing));
    }
```